# how to handle files with JSON data in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm struggling with file upload in express js.
I have this mongoose scheme:

```
{
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 1024,
},

whatToRead: [{ type: String }],

questions: [
    {
        question: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        options: [
            {
                option: String,
                correct: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    default: false,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
],

date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
},
```

and i can easily add a new item to the database with this code:

```
const { title, whatToRead, questions} = req.body;
const quiz = new Quiz({
    title,
    whatToRead,
    questions,
});
try {
    await quiz.save();
    res.send({ msg: "saved", id: quiz.id });
} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err.message);
}
```

However now i need to add an image to the item. I tried doing it with multer, and it worked, but then i can not send json file with all the other information because it has to be a multipart/form-data, not json. How can i send json and file at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send both JSON and File at the same time in the same response. The best practice is to send an imageUrl to the image.

```
res.json({ msg: "saved", id: quiz.id, imageUrl: 'http:\\localhost:8080\testImage.jpg' })
```

The image url you are sending will be referring to the file which is made available using your express server using the static middleware. You will have a public folder in the server and all the items inside will be served from there.

More info here:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use JSON and file at the same time. but you can convert it into 2 requests or you can save your image file into a base64 string and send it with your response in res.json

```
res.json({... your data, 
"base64image" : "base64 string "})
```